# Migrate one of the features in the Android application to iOS

Tags: ios

I plan to make an iOS application in the future. How do you create a dialog like the one below on the iOS app? Like Android. Look at the screenshots.

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OstdL.png)

UPDATE: my goal is to make users choose one of their emails to use for a login or register

Comment: you have to create custom uiview for alert. by default, you cannot have same look as in andoid.

Comment: here is great tutrial to create alerts https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGAlertView

Comment: Maybe you don't understand what I mean. My goal is to get users to choose one of their emails to login / register